# Parallel with a short - MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I was watching the following Razavi video

https://youtu.be/icrn9cYIPUA?list=PLiDoPUX9nLkIw9EnIv_3K19wlcyJ6msYd&t=1564

At 26:04, he says that no current flows through the resistance Rd as voltage across it is zero. But what's to say that current flows the the NMOS cascode on the left? Voltage across that is also zero?

Here's another example of the same thing except with a PMOS load,
https://youtu.be/icrn9cYIPUA?list=PLiDoPUX9nLkIw9EnIv_3K19wlcyJ6msYd&t=2276
At minute 38:45. He did the exact same thing and he said no current flows through the PMOS part becasue voltage across it is zero but isn't that also the case with the NMOS part in that circuit?

Comment: If the NMOS has zero resistance then of course there will be zero voltage across it. Current-carrying conductors are often assumed to be ideal and have zero voltage across them!

Comment: @Chu but the PMOS part didn't have zero resistance and it was ignored?

Comment: I mean zero drain-source resistance.